# How can I refer to a local js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js file that I can't refer to locally.

If I deploy it online and refer to it from there, it works.

```
<script src="http://acwebsite.azurewebsites.net/scripts/table2excel.js"></script>
```

But if I copy the text inside the file and refer to a local js file, it is unable to read it.

```
<script src ="~/Scripts/table2excel.js"></script>
```

Not sure what to do.
This is the js file:

```
//table2excel.js
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    var pluginName = "table2excel",

    defaults = {
        exclude: ".noExl",
        name: "Table2Excel"
    };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
        // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
        // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
        // future instances of the plugin
        //
        this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            var e = this;

            var utf8Heading = "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8\">";
            e.template = {
                head: "<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">" + utf8Heading + "<head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets>",
                sheet: {
                    head: "<x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>",
                    tail: "</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>"
                },
                mid: "</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body>",
                table: {
                    head: "<table>",
                    tail: "</table>"
                },
                foot: "</body></html>"
            };

            e.tableRows = [];

            // get contents of table except for exclude
            $(e.element).each(function (i, o) {
                var tempRows = "";
                $(o).find("tr").not(e.settings.exclude).each(function (i, o) {
                    tempRows += "<tr>" + $(o).html() + "</tr>";
                });
                e.tableRows.push(tempRows);
            });

            e.tableToExcel(e.tableRows, e.settings.name, e.settings.sheetName);
        },

        tableToExcel: function (table, name, sheetName) {
            var e = this, fullTemplate = "", i, link, a;

            e.uri = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,";
            e.base64 = function (s) {
                return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
            };
            e.format = function (s, c) {
                return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                    return c[p];
                });
            };

            sheetName = typeof sheetName === "undefined" ? "Sheet" : sheetName;

            e.ctx = {
                worksheet: name || "Worksheet",
                table: table,
                sheetName: sheetName,
            };

            fullTemplate = e.template.head;

            if ($.isArray(table)) {
                for (i in table) {
                    //fullTemplate += e.template.sheet.head + "{worksheet" + i + "}" + e.template.sheet.tail;
                    fullTemplate += e.template.sheet.head + sheetName + i + e.template.sheet.tail;
                }
            }

            fullTemplate += e.template.mid;

            if ($.isArray(table)) {
                for (i in table) {
                    fullTemplate += e.template.table.head + "{table" + i + "}" + e.template.table.tail;
                }
            }

            fullTemplate += e.template.foot;

            for (i in table) {
                e.ctx["table" + i] = table[i];
            }
            delete e.ctx.table;

            if (typeof msie !== "undefined" && msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
            {
                if (typeof Blob !== "undefined") {
                    //use blobs if we can
                    fullTemplate = [fullTemplate];
                    //convert to array
                    var blob1 = new Blob(fullTemplate, { type: "text/html" });
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob1, getFileName(e.settings));
                } else {
                    //otherwise use the iframe and save
                    //requires a blank iframe on page called txtArea1
                    txtArea1.document.open("text/html", "replace");
                    txtArea1.document.write(e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx));
                    txtArea1.document.close();
                    txtArea1.focus();
                    sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, getFileName(e.settings));
                }

            } else {
                link = e.uri + e.base64(e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx));
                a = document.createElement("a");
                a.download = getFileName(e.settings);
                a.href = link;

                document.body.appendChild(a);

                a.click();

                document.body.removeChild(a);
            }

            return true;
        }
    };

    function getFileName(settings) {
        return (settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel") +
               (settings.fileext ? settings.fileext : ".xlsx");
    }

    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        var e = this;
        e.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(e, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(e, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });

        // chain jQuery functions
        return e;
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "unable to read it"?

Comment: remove your `~`

Comment: You should give your local path to the js file

Comment: I am sure your path for given js file  is incorrect .

Comment: what's your directory/file structure?

Comment: whats your location for scripts folder, is this script referencing any other script, what error are you getting.

Comment: Provide the correct relative path according to the file where you are using it in HTML file.

Comment: There is a method inside the js file that can not be accessed if the file is referred to locally. 
The location is correct; I'm following the VS tool to locate it on my project.

Comment: Doesn't even work when I add the entire script inside <script> tags on the html page.

Comment: then your problem is a different one. Please show the errors you're getting

Answer (score 0):

If you are using relative path, use below way

```
src ="./Scripts/table2excel.js"
```